# Best way to flatten a 2D tensor containing a vector in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the most efficient way to flatten a 2D tensor which is actually a horizontal or vertical vector into a 1D tensor?

Is there a difference in terms of performance between:

```
tf.reshape(w, [-1])
```

and

```
tf.squeeze(w)
```

?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Both [`tf.reshape(w, [-1])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) and [`tf.squeeze(w)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) are "cheap" in that they operate only on the metadata (i.e. the shape) of the given tensor, and don't modify the data itself. Of the two `tf.reshape()` has slightly [simpler logic internally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8242b4dd1b36440e191fef8a07b6f37d8bcee60d/tensorflow/core/kernels/reshape_op.h#L34), but the performance of the two should be indistinguishable.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668542/flatten-batch-in-tensorflow) for flattening while maintaining the batch dimension.

Comment: Obvious when you look at the documentation but for the unaware: note that `squeeze` really only works for dimensions of size 1, i.e. does not flatten e.g. 2x2 arrays (as pointed out in Calimero's answer).

Answer (score 9):

For a simple 2D tensor the two should function identically, as mentioned by @sv_jan5. However, please note that `tf.squeeze(w)` only squeezes the first layer in the case of a multilayer tensor, whereas `tf.reshape(w,[-1])` will flatten the entire tensor regardless of depth.

For example, let's look at

```
w = [[1,2,],[3,4]]
```

now the output of the two functions will no longer be the same. `tf.squeeze(w)`will output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)>
```

while `tf.reshape(w,[-1])` will output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)>
```