# Flatten batch in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have an input to tensorflow of shape `[None, 9, 2]` (where the `None` is batch).

To perform further actions (e.g. matmul) on it I need to transform it to `[None, 18]` shape. How to do it?

Answer (score 46):

You can do it easily with tf.reshape() without knowing the batch size.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 9,2])
shape = x.get_shape().as_list()        # a list: [None, 9, 2]
dim = numpy.prod(shape[1:])            # dim = prod(9,2) = 18
x2 = tf.reshape(x, [-1, dim])           # -1 means "all"
```

The `-1` in the last line means the whole column no matter what the batchsize is in the runtime. You can see it in [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape).

---

## Update: shape = [None, 3, None]

Thanks @kbrose. For the cases where more than 1 dimension are undefined, we can use [tf.shape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape?hl=zh-tw) with [tf.reduce_prod()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_prod) alternatively.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3, None])
dim = tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(x)[1:])
x2 = tf.reshape(x, [-1, dim])
```

tf.shape() returns a shape Tensor which can be evaluated in runtime. The difference between tf.get_shape() and tf.shape() can be seen [in the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#tensor_shapes).

I also tried tf.contrib.layers.flatten() in another . It is simplest for the first case, but it can't handle the second.

Comment: This works well if you know the size of all the other dimensions, but does not if the other dimensions have unknown size. E.g. `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 9, None])`

Comment: thanks @kbrose. I've updated the answer for the case.

Comment: @weitang114 Awesome!

Comment: i was stuck with reshape, tf.reduce_prod did the trick for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if `x2` is later passed into a `dynamic_rnn`. Produces `ValueError: Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None.`

Comment: Edit queue is full; the first link for tf.reshape() is broken and should probably go here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape?hl=zh-tw

Answer (score 18):

```
flat_inputs = tf.layers.flatten(inputs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic reshaping to get value of batch dimension through `tf.batch` during runtime, calculate the whole set of new dimensions into `tf.reshape`. Here's an example of reshaping flat list into square matrix without knowing list length.

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession("")
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
# get [9]
ashape = tf.shape(a)
# slice the list from 0th to 1st position
ashape0 = tf.slice(ashape, [0], [1])
# reshape list to scalar, ie from [9] to 9
ashape0_flat = tf.reshape(ashape0, ())
# tf.sqrt doesn't support int, so cast to float
ashape0_flat_float = tf.to_float(ashape0_flat)
newshape0 = tf.sqrt(ashape0_flat_float)
# convert [3, 3] Python list into [3, 3] Tensor
newshape = tf.pack([newshape0, newshape0])
# tf.reshape doesn't accept float, so convert back to int
newshape_int = tf.to_int32(newshape)
a_reshaped = tf.reshape(a, newshape_int)
sess.run(a_reshaped, feed_dict={a: np.ones((9))})
```

You should see

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I do not see any method `tf.batch` in this solution or in Tensorflow...