# Reshape TensorFlow tensor inside Keras loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to reshape a TF tensor inside of a custom Keras loss function? I'm defining this custom loss function for a convolutional neural network?

```py
def custom_loss(x, x_hat):
    """
    Custom loss function for training background extraction networks (autoencoders)
    """

    #flatten x, x_hat before computing mean, median
    shape = x_hat.get_shape().as_list()
    batch_size = shape[0]
    image_size = np.prod(shape[1:])

    x = tf.reshape(x, [batch_size, image_size])
    x_hat = tf.reshape(x_hat, [batch_size, image_size]) 

    B0 = reduce_median(tf.transpose(x_hat))
    # I divide by sigma in the next step. So I add a small float32 to F0
    # so as to prevent sigma from becoming 0 or Nan.

    F0 = tf.abs(x_hat - B0) + 1e-10

    sigma = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(F0 / 0.5), axis=0)

    background_term = tf.reduce_mean(F0 / sigma, axis=-1)

    bce = binary_crossentropy(x, x_hat)

    loss = bce + background_term 

    return loss
```

In addition to computing the standard `binary_crossentropy` an additional `background_term` is added into the loss. This term incentives the network to predict images close the median of a batch. Since the outputs of the CNN are 2d and `reduce_median` works better with 1d arrays I have to reshape the images into 1d arrays. When I try to train this network I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 162, in <module>
    autoencoder = build_conv_autoencoder(lambda_W, input_shape, num_filters, optimizer, custom_loss)
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 136, in build_conv_autoencoder
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics=[mean_squared_error])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 594, in compile
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 667, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 318, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 26, in custom_loss
    x = tf.reshape(x, [batch_size, image_size])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2448, in reshape
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 494, in apply_op
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 491, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 710, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 441, in make_tensor_proto
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 441, in <listcomp>
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None
```

It seems like Keras is calling `custom_loss` before the TensorFlow graph is instantiated. This makes `batch_size` None instead of the actual value. Is there a proper way to reshape tensors inside loss functions to this error is avoided? You can look at the full code [here](https://gitlab.com/mdornfe1/dolphin_tagger/blob/master/stackoverflow.py) .

Comment: Have you tried defining a `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape` in either first layer or `Input` layer?

Comment: Could you check the value of `shape` after using `get_shape().as_list()`? I suppose `x` and `x_hat` are correct tensors but if you could check they are correct will greatly help solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a proper way to reshape tensors...

If you are using Keras you should use the `K.reshape(x,shape)` method, which is a wrapper for `tf.reshape(x,shape)` as we can see in the [docs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1726-L1736).

I also notice you are using `get_shape()` to obtain your tensor shape, when on Keras you can do this with `K.int_shape(x)` as also mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L469-L496), like this:

```
shape = K.int_shape(x_hat)
```

Besides that there are several other operations you do directly calling your Tensorflow import, instead of the Keras Backend (like `tf.abs()`, `tf.reduce_mean()`, `tf.transpose()`, etc.). You should consider using its corresponding wrappers in the keras backend to have uniform notation and guarantee a more regular behaviour. Also, by using the Keras backend you are giving your program compatibility with both Theano and Tensorflow, so it is a big plus you should consider.

Additionally, some `TypeError` may appear when working with tensors with undefined dimension(s). Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668542/flatten-batch-in-tensorflow) where they explain about reshaping tensors with undefined dimensions. Also, for its equivalent in Keras, check [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171247/reshape-tensor-in-custom-loss-function/45173396#45173396) question, where in an answer I explain how to achieve that using Keras with Tensorflow as backend.

...Now regarding your code. Basically, as you have some undefined dimensions, you can pass the value -1 to have it infer the shape no matter what size it could be (it is explained in the first linked question, but can also be seen in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)). Something like:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, image_size])
```

Or using Keras backend:

```
x = K.reshape(x, [-1, image_size])
```