# Reshape tensor in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056512/reshape-tensorflow-tensor-inside-keras-loss-function). I am trying to devise a loss function in keras given as:

```py
def depth_loss_func(lr):
    def loss(actual_depth,pred_depth):
        actual_shape = actual_depth.get_shape().as_list()
        dim = np.prod(actual_shape[1:])
        actual_vec = K.reshape(actual_depth,[-1,dim])
        pred_vec = K.reshape(pred_depth,[-1,dim])
        di = K.log(pred_vec)-K.log(actual_vec)
        di_mean = K.mean(di)
        sq_mean = K.mean(K.square(di))

        return (sq_mean - (lr*di_mean*di_mean))
    return loss
```

based on the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668542/flatten-batch-in-tensorflow). However, I am getting an error:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Specifically this statement gives the following output

```
(Pdb) actual_depth.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)])
```

The backend is TensorFlow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce you exception with a Tensor of shape `(None, None, None, 9)`, when calling `np.prod()` like this:

```
from keras import backend as K

#create tensor placeholder
z = K.placeholder(shape=(None, None, None, 9))
#obtain its static shape with int_shape from Keras
actual_shape = K.int_shape(z)
#obtain product, error fires here... TypeError between None and None
dim = np.prod(actual_shape[1:])
```

This happens because you are trying to multiply two elements of type `None`, even though you sliced your `actual_shape` (as more than 1 elements where `None`). In some cases you can even get `TypeError` between `None` and `int`, if only one none-type element remains after slicing.

Taking a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668542/flatten-batch-in-tensorflow) you mentioned, they specify what to do in those situations, quoting from it:

> For the cases where more than 1 dimension are undefined, we can use **tf.shape()** with **tf.reduce_prod()** alternatively.

Based on that, we can translate those operations to the Keras API, by using `K.shape()` ([docs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L438-L466)) and `K.prod()` ([docs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1195-L1210)), respectively:

```
z = K.placeholder(shape=(None, None, None, 9))
#obtain Real shape and calculate dim with prod, no TypeError this time
dim = K.prod(K.shape(z)[1:])
#reshape
z2 = K.reshape(z, [-1,dim])
```

Also, for the case where only one dimension is undefined remember to use `K.int_shape(z)` or its wrapper `K.get_variable_shape(z)` instead of just `get_shape()`, as also defined in the backend ([docs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L469-L496)). Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Glad to see this solved your problem, good luck with your coding. If you found this answer useful consider also upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrayCygnus!