# Reshape Tensor from shape (n, h, w, c) to (n, h * w, c)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Looking at [Best way to flatten a 2D tensor containing a vector in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194151/best-way-to-flatten-a-2d-tensor-containing-a-vector-in-tensorflow) I see how to flatten a 2D tensor to a 1D tensor in TensorFlow but how do I flatten a 4D Tensor to a 3D Tensor with TensorFlow functions?

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.random_normal([n, h, w, c], mean=1, stddev=4)
Y = ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) function should work for you:

```
Y = tf.reshape(X, (n, h*w, c))
```